# Is it possible to set the order of returned folder item's in the Box REST API?

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

The response has the order the results were returned in, but is it possible to set the order in the request?

It is possible to set the limit and offset when executing the Get a Folder’s Items, but this functionality seems incomplete if the order can't be supplied.

As per the [documentation](https://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-retrieve-a-folders-items) example, a limit and offset URL parameter can be set.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/items?limit=2&offset=0 \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it currently isn't possible to customize the order of items returned by the API.

The limit and offset parameters are used to page through large arrays, since it's possible for a folder to have thousands of items which can't all be returned in a single response.

Comment: Could setting the order of results be added as a feature request?

Comment: I believe that this feature is already on our backlog and it's something we're looking into.